# exceptions.ImportError: cannot import name TwitterAPI

Tags: python, api, twitter

Keep getting this error and not sure why,

```
exceptions.ImportError: cannot import name TwitterAPI
```

TwitterAPI library is already downloaded, I download it first from pip install twitterapi, didnt work, uninstall it and download the .zip file for it, and tried to install it using

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

didnt work too, still getting the same error, any ideas?

the code:

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI

TRACK_TERM = 'NBA'

api = TwitterAPI(consumer_key='__', consumer_secret='__', access_token_key='__', access_token_secret='__')

r = api.request('statuses/filter', {'track': TRACK_TERM})

for item in r:
    print (item['text'] if 'text' in item else item)
```

Comment: What API lib are you using? Importing from a CamelCase module/package looks bad already.

Answer (score 1):

Please write this command that set:

```
pip install python-twitter
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you installed TwitterAPI from a zip file, the package is not necessarily in a path where Python will see it. That is why import fails. Your best bet is to try installing with pip again, but this time use the proper case since pip is case sensitive:

```
pip install TwitterAPI
```

Comment: I used that the first time I downloaded TwitterAPI, didn't work too, I fixed the error by going to the files and putting the TwitterAPI manually to the site-package.

Comment: When you ran "pip install TwitterAPI" were there errors?

Comment: Try this: cd into an empty folder, run the python interpreter and type "from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI". If that produces no error, then TwitterAPI is installed properly which would point to a circular reference.

Answer (score 0):

You should to install requests (or upgrade them) like in this [issue](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI/issues/46).

```
pip install requests
```

or

```
pip install --upgrade requests
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably need to set PYTHONPATH:

```
export PYTHONPATH=`pwd`
```